# How to prevent same data on same date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an issue with tracking IPs. The user IP tracking code is added in post_controller hook in Codeigniter.

When the controller ends the IP is added in DB. if a user visits a page where multiple controllers(for ex APIs) are triggered then multiple times the IP tracker hook is triggered.

Due to multiple hook triggers within milliseconds, multiple same IPs are added. Even though there is a check if IP exists in DB on today's date then don't add but that happens in milliseconds and no IP in DB present at that millisecond so multiple IPs get added.

**How can I prevent duplicate IPs on the same date if the hook is triggered multiple times in milliseconds?**

Comment: Create unique index by `(IP, date)`. But rememeber that trigger which tries to insert duplicated record will fail causing the whole query fail. To avoid this use `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT .. ODKU`.

Comment: my date column is an date+time column, I have to change it to date only or there is any way to add index still by date only?

Comment: *my date column is an date+time column* It doesn't affect anything.

Comment: it will not check time too for uniqueness?

Comment: Server will check fields combination specified in unique index. If it contains 2 columns of BIGINT and DATETIME datatypes then the record which have both values equal to ones already existed in any another record will be ejected. If one column value is equal and another is not (even when it is equal to the value in another record) insert will success.

Comment: ok thanks so i have to make the datetime as date column otherwise it may think a separate record.

Comment: *i have to make the datetime as date column* I'd not recommend... a day is too wide granularity.